# bootstrap-daterangepicker change custom range selection behavior

Tags: jquery, daterangepicker

Does anyone know a way to change how [bootstrap-daterangepicker](https://github.com/dangrossman/bootstrap-daterangepicker) allows a user to select a custom date range?

Currently, it seems to think that first clicked date is the 'From' date and the second is the 'To' date. The problem with this is if the user wants a date range in the past and decides to choose first the 'To' date since it is on the visible calendar, and then browse back through the calendar and choose the 'From' date.

I'd like to change it so that whatever date is selected first, is considered the 'From' date. And the second date is set as 'To' date, unless the second date is earlier, in which case, it should swap the dates around.

I understand the user can simply correct the date on the input field, but that defeats the use of the calendar UI.

I am hoping someone has already done a similar approach. If not, I may have to resort to creating a version of this plugin. (From code, it seems to be the clickDate function that I need to be concerned about.)

Comment: I already encountered this kind of problem in bootstrap, and what I did is to used another library and edit some code. If you want the code, just feedback this comment and I will put in the answer. ^_^

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean, but I do not think it is a problem on bootstrap.

Comment: Yeah, you're right. Can you post your code here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, as I didn't want to switch to a different date range picker, I decided to stick with this one but change its `clickDate` behaviour. The code I use for the `clickDate` is this, which has a comment on how it sets the start and end dates. Note the commented out original behaviour, followed by new block which dictates the new behaviour. Note also after this, the added `else` condition for the `if (this.singleDatePicker)` block:

```
    clickDate: function(e) {

        if (!$(e.target).hasClass('available')) return;

        var title = $(e.target).attr('data-title');
        var row = title.substr(1, 1);
        var col = title.substr(3, 1);
        var cal = $(e.target).parents('.calendar');
        var date = cal.hasClass('left') ? this.leftCalendar.calendar[row][col] : this.rightCalendar.calendar[row][col];

        // This was the original behaviour which I replaced below.
        //
        // this function needs to do a few things:
        // * alternate between selecting a start and end date for the range,
        // * if the time picker is enabled, apply the hour/minute/second from the select boxes to the clicked date
        // * if autoapply is enabled, and an end date was chosen, apply the selection
        // * if single date picker mode, and time picker isn't enabled, apply the selection immediately
        //
        // if (this.endDate || date.isBefore(this.startDate)) {
        //     if (this.timePicker) {
        //         var hour = parseInt(this.container.find('.left .hourselect').val(), 10);
        //         if (!this.timePicker24Hour) {
        //             var ampm = cal.find('.ampmselect').val();
        //             if (ampm === 'PM' && hour < 12)
        //                 hour += 12;
        //             if (ampm === 'AM' && hour === 12)
        //                 hour = 0;
        //         }
        //         var minute = parseInt(this.container.find('.left .minuteselect').val(), 10);
        //         var second = this.timePickerSeconds ? parseInt(this.container.find('.left .secondselect').val(), 10) : 0;
        //         date = date.clone().hour(hour).minute(minute).second(second);
        //     }
        //     this.endDate = null;
        //     this.setStartDate(date.clone());
        // } else {
        //     if (this.timePicker) {
        //         var hour = parseInt(this.container.find('.right .hourselect').val(), 10);
        //         if (!this.timePicker24Hour) {
        //             var ampm = this.container.find('.right .ampmselect').val();
        //             if (ampm === 'PM' && hour < 12)
        //                 hour += 12;
        //             if (ampm === 'AM' && hour === 12)
        //                 hour = 0;
        //         }
        //         var minute = parseInt(this.container.find('.right .minuteselect').val(), 10);
        //         var second = this.timePickerSeconds ? parseInt(this.container.find('.right .secondselect').val(), 10) : 0;
        //         date = date.clone().hour(hour).minute(minute).second(second);
        //     }
        //     this.setEndDate(date.clone());
        //     if (this.autoApply)
        //         this.clickApply();
        // }


        // Change the behaviour as follows:
        // - If the first date selected, assign it to the start date.
        // - When the second date is selected, check if it is later than (or equal to) the first date (which is currently the start date). 
        //   If the second date is later than (or is equal to) the first date, then make it the end date.
        //   If the second date is earlier than the first date, make the first date the end date, and make the second date the start date. 
        // - If auto-apply is off, and another date is selected, then treat it as the first date go back to rule #1.
        if (this.startDate && !this.endDate) {
            if (date.isSame(this.startDate) || date.isAfter(this.startDate)) {
                if (this.timePicker) {
                    var hour = parseInt(this.container.find('.left .hourselect').val(), 10);
                    if (!this.timePicker24Hour) {
                        var ampm = cal.find('.ampmselect').val();
                        if (ampm === 'PM' && hour < 12)
                            hour += 12;
                        if (ampm === 'AM' && hour === 12)
                            hour = 0;
                    }
                    var minute = parseInt(this.container.find('.left .minuteselect').val(), 10);
                    var second = this.timePickerSeconds ? parseInt(this.container.find('.left .secondselect').val(), 10) : 0;
                    date = date.clone().hour(hour).minute(minute).second(second);
                }
                this.setEndDate(date.clone());
            } 
            else {
                if (this.timePicker) {
                    var hour = parseInt(this.container.find('.left .hourselect').val(), 10);
                    if (!this.timePicker24Hour) {
                        var ampm = cal.find('.ampmselect').val();
                        if (ampm === 'PM' && hour < 12)
                            hour += 12;
                        if (ampm === 'AM' && hour === 12)
                            hour = 0;
                    }
                    var minute = parseInt(this.container.find('.left .minuteselect').val(), 10);
                    var second = this.timePickerSeconds ? parseInt(this.container.find('.left .secondselect').val(), 10) : 0;
                    date = date.clone().hour(hour).minute(minute).second(second);
                }
                this.endDate = this.startDate.clone();
                this.setStartDate(date.clone());
            } 
        }
        else {
            if (this.timePicker) {
                var hour = parseInt(this.container.find('.right .hourselect').val(), 10);
                if (!this.timePicker24Hour) {
                    var ampm = this.container.find('.right .ampmselect').val();
                    if (ampm === 'PM' && hour < 12)
                        hour += 12;
                    if (ampm === 'AM' && hour === 12)
                        hour = 0;
                }
                var minute = parseInt(this.container.find('.right .minuteselect').val(), 10);
                var second = this.timePickerSeconds ? parseInt(this.container.find('.right .secondselect').val(), 10) : 0;
                date = date.clone().hour(hour).minute(minute).second(second);
            }
            this.setStartDate(date.clone());
            this.endDate = null;
        }

        if (this.singleDatePicker) {
            this.setEndDate(this.startDate);
            if (!this.timePicker)
                this.clickApply();
        } 
        // I also added this else condition:
        // If a date range picker, and both dates are selected, and it is auto-apply, trigger clickApply.
        else if (this.autoApply && !this.timePicker && this.startDate && this.endDate && !this.startDate.isSame(this.endDate)) {
            this.clickApply();
        }

        this.updateView();

    },
```

I also commented out completely the `hoverDate` function as I found it confusing that the input field values are changing as I hover the calendar. But that is my personal preference.

*UPDATE*

If you wish to see what I did, you can check it on GitHub [here](https://github.com/frankfajardo/bootstrap-daterangepicker).

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for my answer earlier, here I updated my code. Maybe this would help.

[CLICK HERE FOR THE CODE](http:////jsfiddle.net/6boa11cn/)

Comment: thanks for your reply. I'm actually using the daterangepicker with jqGrid's filter field so I only have one input field for the date range.